# Eclipse "\Android Private Libraries" vs "\Referenced Libraries"

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries

I've noticed that some libraries need to be added to build path manually (i.e. "Referenced Libraries") whereas other libraries works fine if I simply put the jar in `\libs` folder (i.e. "Android Private Libraries").

For example android support library works fine if it is manually added to the build path, But what is the reason?

I haven't understood what is the difference and when I should choose one option over the other and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android Libraries** contains

1. Classes and/or Java codes
2. Jar Files, and
3. Resources

They are also a project. They cannot be run directly, but compiled. **Private Libraries** doesn't have resources, they are jar files that contains .class files

> For example android support library works fine if is added to build
>   path... but what is the reason?

Specifically, there are useful classes introduced in Honeycomb and above like `Fragment`. You might want to use `Fragment` for Gingerbread? Use android support library.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Could I get some side effect if always add all the libraries in build path as referenced libraries?

Comment: If JAR Files, based on my experience, you might get `ClassNotFoundException` if you exported it in an APK File (With Proguard enabled). Make sure you've configured correctly the proguard.

Comment: In Project Libraries, conflicts in jar files. For example, the library project has support library while the application project also has support library, you will get a compilation because they have same classes and filename.

Comment: @Glenn, **-1, Doesn't answer the question.** The question is not asking about "Android Dependencies", Both "private libraries" and "referenced libraries" don't have `res`. Your post doesn't answer the question at all.